# I need help solving for the gradient

Tags: calculus

Given that the Directional derivative at $(2,1)$ towards $(1,3)$ is $\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$ and the directional derivative of the same gradient at $(2,1)$ towards $(5,5)$ is one, FIND the partial derivatives that constitute the gradient. To me, the logical solution would be that since $\nabla F * u=1$ for the second point, couldn't you just take the inverse of the unitized vector to find the gradient?

Comment: I don't think so. But write the gradient as $(a,b)$. The given information will give you two equations in $a$ and $b$ (assuming the function is differentiable at $(2,1)$). For example the first piece of information tells you $a\cdot{-1\over\sqrt 5}+b\cdot{2\over\sqrt 5}={-2\over\sqrt5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know that for any non-zero vector $(u,v),$ the directional derivative at $(a,b)$ toward the point $(a+u,b+v)$ is given by $$\frac1{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\nabla f(a,b)\cdot(u,v)=\frac1{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\left(f_x(a,b)u+f_y(a,b)v\right)$$ You've been given $(a,b)=(2,1)$ and for each of the two values of the directional derivative you've been given, you were told $(a+u,b+v),$ which will allow you to find the corresponding $u,v$. Can you take it from there and solve the resulting linear system of two equations in two variables--namely, for $f_x(2,1)$ and $f_y(2,1)$?

---

**Added**: As for your suggested alternative approach, the issue is that there is *no such thing* as "the inverse" of a vector in the sense that you mean, so you can't do any such thing.

Why is that? Well, let's suppose that there were some vector $u\in\Bbb R^n$ with an "inverse" of this sort--that is, something that allows us to "undo" the dot product. That would mean that for any $v,w\in\Bbb R^n,$ we would have $v\cdot u=w\cdot u$ if and only if $v=w.$ If $n>1,$ though, this turns out to be impossible.

> **Proof**: By way of contradiction, suppose some $u\in\Bbb R^n$ has the desired "invertibility" property for some $n>1.$

Observe that $u$ cannot be the zero vector, since $v\cdot\vec 0=0$ for all $v\in\Bbb R^n.$

> Now, let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be the standard ordered basis for $\Bbb R^n.$ Then there exist unique $c_1,...,c_n\in\Bbb R$ such that $$u=c_1e_1+\cdots+c_ne_n $$ and at least one $c_j\ne 0.$. There are two cases to consider.
>
> First, let's suppose that *exactly* one $c_j\ne0.$ Since $n>1,$ then there is some $1\le i\le n$ such that $i\ne j.$ But then $$e_i\cdot u=e_i\cdot(c_je_j)=c_j(e_i\cdot e_j)=c_j\vec0=0=\vec0\cdot u,$$ but $e_i\ne\vec0,$ contradicting our assumption about $u.$
>
> Therefore, there exist $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $i\ne j$ such that $c_i,c_j\ne0.$ Note that $$u\cdot u=c_1^2+\cdots+c_n^2>0.$$ Now, let $$v=e_i-\frac{e_i\cdot u}{u\cdot u}u.$$ Note that $$\begin{align}e_j\cdot v &= e_j\cdot\left(e_i-\frac{e_i\cdot u}{u\cdot u}e_i\right)\\ &= e_j\cdot e_i-\frac{e_i\cdot u}{u\cdot u}(e_j\cdot u)\\ &= -\frac{c_i}{u\cdot u}(e_j\cdot u)\\ &= \frac{c_ic_j}{u\cdot u}\\ &\ne0,\end{align}$$ so $v\ne\vec0.$ However, $$\begin{align}v\cdot u &= \left(e_i-\frac{e_i\cdot u}{u\cdot u}u\right)\cdot u\\ &= e_i\cdot u-\frac{e_i\cdot u}{u\cdot u}(u\cdot u)\\ &= e_i\cdot u- e_i\cdot u\\ &= 0\\ &=\vec0\cdot u,\end{align}$$ But this is impossible, based on our assumption about $u$.
>
> Since assuming that there is such a $u$ led to an impossibility, then no such $u$ exists. $\Box$

Now, in the $n=1$ case, it works for non-zero vectors, but there, your vectors are scalars, your dot product is the usual product, and your gradient is just the derivative.

The upshot is this: trying to "invert" a dot product is (exactly) like trying to find "the" solution to a linear equation in several variables: impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Your gradient at $(2,1)$ is given by some vector $\left<x,y\right>$. We know that $\frac{\left<x,y\right>\cdot\left<-1,2\right>}{|\left<-1,2\right>|}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}$ and that $\frac{\left<x,y\right>\cdot\left<3,4\right>}{|\left<3,4\right>|}=1$. Simplifying, we get

$\left<x,y\right>\cdot\left<-1,2\right>=-2 \\
\left<x,y\right>\cdot\left<3,4\right>=5$

...or,

$-x+2y=-2\\
3x+4y=5$

These equations are solvable using ordinary algebra. Is this what you were looking for?

The reason you can't do some kind of inverse with the unit vector is that the dot product is not a one-to-one map, and therefore not invertible. If $v\cdot u$ is known and $u$ is known, that's not enough information to recover $v$, because lots of different vectors $v$ could give you the same dot product with $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\nabla F=(f_x, f_y).$ Then $\nabla F_{(1,3)}=\frac{f_x+3f_y}{\sqrt10}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt5}$ and $\nabla F_{(5,5)}=\frac{5f_x+5f_y}{5\sqrt2}=\frac{f_x+f_y}{\sqrt2}=1$. Then if you solve the equations yo will find $f_y=\frac{-3}{\sqrt2}$ and $f_x=\frac{5}{\sqrt2}$. So $$f_x(2,1)=\frac{5}{\sqrt2}\qquad and \qquad f_y(2,1)=\frac{-3}{\sqrt2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Primer**
No, you cannot since the operation scalar product is not invertible in the sense there is no "action" that can reverse it as:
$T_u(\nabla f(a)*u)\neq\nabla f(a)$
And this is so since the operation scalar product is not injective - remember from linear algebra.

**Theory**
A function is differentiable at some point iff it is approximated by a linear operator (matrix):
$f(a+v)\approx f(a)+A v+r(v)$
The directional derivatives become in this manner:
$\partial_v f(a)=A v$
The partial derivatives are defined as the ones along basis vectors:
$\partial_i f(a):=\partial_{e_i}f(a)$

**Problem**
The question is now to find underlying matrix for your directional derivatives (solving a system of linear equations) and then to compute the partial derivatives (applying the matrix on basis vectors).

**Solution**
In your case that is: $A v=a$
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\end{pmatrix}$$
And: $A w=b$
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5\\5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\end{pmatrix}$$
Thus:
$a=\frac{1}{20}(3-2\sqrt 5)$, $b=\frac{1}{20}(1+2\sqrt 5)$
Now, applying this to the basis vectors: $A e_1=c$
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{20}(3-2\sqrt 5)&\frac{1}{20}(1+2\sqrt 5)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{20}(3-2\sqrt 5)\end{pmatrix}$$
And similar: $A e_2=d$
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{20}(3-2\sqrt 5)&\frac{1}{20}(1+2\sqrt 5)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{20}(1+2\sqrt 5)\end{pmatrix}$$
Concluding:
$\partial_1 f(a)=\frac{1}{20}(3-2\sqrt 5)$, $\partial_2 f(a)=\frac{1}{20}(1+2\sqrt 5)$

**Addendum**
Note, that the point where your function is differentiable was not occuring in *any* calculation!